# JSON.parse gives SyntaxError inside a for loop with array

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array with direction renderer json's which are stringified.

```
array[1].direction = '{\"routes\":[{\"bounds\":\"\....'
array[1].direction = '{\"routes\":[{\"bounds\":\"\....'
.
.
```

This is what i did to render those json's on my map.

```
for (var x=2; x<array.length; x++) {

        renderDirections(array[x].direction);
    }

function renderDirections(result){

     var directionRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

       myDirections = JSON.parse(result, function(name, value){

         if(/^LatLngPlaceHolder\(/.test(value)) { 
                    var match = /LatLngPlaceHolder\(([^,]+),([^,]+)\)/.exec(value);
                    return new google.maps.LatLng(match[1], match[2]);
                } 
         else{
           return value;
         }
        });

      directionRenderer.setMap(map);
      directionRenderer.setDirections(myDirections);
      directionRenderer.setOptions({suppressMarkers:true,preserveViewport:true});
    }
```

Doing this gives a `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \"` error at the JSON.parse line.

However, if i do:

```
for (var x=2; x<array.length; x++) {

        var examplejson = '{\"routes\":[{\"bounds\":\"\....'; //note that its an example json which i logged from `array[x].direction`
        renderDirections(examplejson);
    }
```

it renders the json.

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes? It's a javascript object, it has to contain quotes to identify properties. It's not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is only needed when you're creating the JSON inside a string to be parsed into an object.  Remove `\` from your first example and you'll have better luck.

```
array[1].direction = {"routes":[{"bounds":"....
```

The `\` tells the parser that "don't treat the quote as a terminator, but as a character."  Outside a quoted string, it's just incorrect.

Comment: One could argue that the OP has a string in the example (last code snippet).

Comment: *sigh* yes we all write in strings.  But some are treated by the parser as "string types" and others as "syntactical units".  The first example, the OP is creating a JSON object as a syntactical unit, in the second, he's created a string that is parsed in to a JSON object.

Comment: Sorry but i couldn't understand what you mean. it is the same string in the array and in the second example. but when i assign it to a var (the same string with backslash) instead of an array it works.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the `var examplejson = '{\"routes\":[{\"bounds\":\"\....';` part in the last example. The single quotes denote a string. What the OP posted in the first part is not JSON but just invalid JavaScript. [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @PaulProgrammer If this were true, you'd get an error a lot sooner than the parse. `var obj = {\"key\": []};` = "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: In your first example, the `\"` is syntactically incorrect, because the `\` is not a valid token in that structure.  It's required when you're trying to put `"` inside a string, to indicate that the `"` is not a string terminator, but a character inside the string.  When creating the JSON object directly, don't escape the outside quotes.

Comment: Well yeah, I'm not talking about the first example but the code the OP  seems to actually run (the last part). And again, there is no such thing as a JSON object. What you are referring to are *object initializers* or *object literals* in JS. JSON is a textual data exchange format.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to create the direction objects that way. If you are constructing a dynamic json then you should do something like this:

```
var array = [];
var obj = {
   key: "value",
   key2: "value2",
   key3: 3
};
array.push(obj);
```

If you receive the value for key and key2 from a server then you can just substitute the hard-coded string with the variable containing the value. Coding your objects in the above manner is easier to maintain too. It's horrendous to write a manually encoded json object. You'll never know what mistakes will creep in when you edit them. **If you need to serialize that array for storage you can just JSON.stringify(array)** and that will return a json encoded string that you can transmit over the wire or even store in localStorage.

With the approach I showed you, you wouldn't need a JSON.parse at all so you save yourself from calling JSON.parse in a loop unnecessarily. If you have a different reason for creating the json object like the way you are, you should probably state that in your question. But either way, you shouldn't have to do that.